# Detect a "dark" portal in space from the planets surface

Tags: science-fiction

**Scenario:**
Earth like planet with a moon similar to ours.
A portal, with approx. 15ft radius, appears between the planet and its moon.
The portal does not reflect light, nor emmit any light so nothing can be seen, when looking at it.

**Goal:**
Would it be possible for someone on the planet notice the portal?
...through it either blocking a known star in the night sky or by creating a small dot on the moon?

Portal position can be anywhere between the planet and moon, and the observer would be on the night side of the planet - there would be no local light pollution in the observers location.
Portal can "follow" rotation of planet if needed, to help its detection.

I was hoping for the story I am writing to have the portal be detected by someone using a simple telescope, but I feel that the size of the portal may be too small still no matter how close it is to the planet.

EDIT: Portal needs to appear in space, between the moon and up to 2000km from the planet surface.

Comment: this could be easy if it comes directly between the earth and moon. However, some amateurs cant find the moon landing location with their low powered telescopes and many professional grade telescopes cant focus on something as close as the moon.

Comment: If the portal is subject to gravity, then it will orbit with a different period than the moon, and won't remain on the direct line between planet and moon. Maybe it will have a hyperbolic orbit! Depends upon it's mass. If the portal is NOT subject to gravity, then the velocity of the planet and star and galaxy --which are in motion-- will abandon the portal to deep space, far from the solar system, within few minutes. If the portal is magical, then you can have any answer you like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that you want to see the dark disk against the bright background of the moon; seeing a black disk against the black background of the night sky is obviously a non-starter.

A 4.5 meters wide disk at a distance of 2,000,000 meters has an angular diameter of a little less than 0.5 arc seconds. Can we see a black dot half an arc-second wide on the bright background of the Moon with an amateur-level telescope?

Let's assume that the same [alien space bat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alien_space_bats) magic which created the portal makes it so that the portal sits always in the same spot along the Earth-Moon radius, so that the amateur astronomer has a fighting chance to see it.

The angular resolution (= separation power) of a telescope located at the bottom of the ocean of air we call the atmosphere is limited by two factors:

- The [separation power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airy_disk) of the optical system itself, which, for an ideal lens with no aberrations, goes $\theta = 1.22 \frac \lambda d$, where $\lambda$ is the wavelength of interest and $d$ is the (physical) size of the aperture, giving $\theta$ in radians.

  In priciple, you can make your objective lens or mirror as large as needed in order to get an angular resolution as good as you want. Plugging in numbers for $\lambda =$ 555 nm, we get

  - For a 100 mm telescope, you get a theoretical separation power of 1.4 arc-seconds. Can't see the portal.
  - For a 200 mm telescope, you get a theoretical resolution of 0.7 arc-seconds. Can't see the portal.
  - For an (expensive) 280 mm telescope, you get a theoretical separation power of 0.5 arc-seconds. Can barely barely see the portal, were it not for the turbulence of the atmosphere.

    A decent 280 mm telescope will cost you about 2500 euros.
- The unfortunate effect of the atmosphere itself, known as [astronomical seeing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astronomical_seeing). The atmosphere is not made of optical glass, it is made of turbulent air. The turbulence distorts the nice plane wavefronts of the light coming in from the distant astronomical objects, with the effect that stars appear to flicker and details are smeared. Astronomical seeing limits the angular resolution of earth-based telescopes to about 1 or 2 arc-seconds, depending on the specific place and the specific night, unless you go to the top of a tall mountain, where you *may* (or may not, depends on luck) get an exceptionally good seeing of about 0.5 arc-second.

  To combat astronomical seeing you can use [adaptive optics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptive_optics); a good amateur-level adaptive optics module will reduce seeing by 30% to maybe 50%.

So, overall, a dedicated amateur who has a few thousand euros to spend on kit, and it located in a good spot, and happens to look at just the right patch of the Moon, *might*, just *might* see a dark spot, half an arc-second wide, on the bright background of the Moon.

Which creates a problem. The dark dot will literally be at the resolution limit of the kit. Maybe it's something new; but most likely, will the amateur astronomer think, it's some old lunar crater.

To be extremely optimistic, let's assume that *two* such dedicated amateur astronomers observe the Moon at the same time, in places some distance away, and take digital pictures. Then, by a stroke of luck, they exchange pictures and run some comparison software on them. And they see that while 99.9999% of the pixels coincide, there is *one* pixel which differs between the two images.

Now they have a mystery to solve, and they involve other amateur astronomers. The mystery takes a life of its own, and soon the real astronomers are intrigued. Real astronomers have better telescopes, and the alien-space-bat-fixed position of the dark spot is easy to calculate from basic trigonometry. The portal is officially found.

To recapitulate:

- You need two dedicated moderately rich amateur astronomers, living in two good places for astronomical observation, who just so happened to take pictures of the same uninteresting place on the Moon with their expensive kit on the same night at the same time.
- They must be part of a group where they routinely exchange pictures.
- At least one of them must have an unexplainable curiosity to run a computerized image comparison on the pictures.

That's what your story must tell, and be embellished by the skill of the story teller.

Comment: Wow....Thanks for that info!
I may need to think about some more Alien Space Bat magic, and give the atronomer a more futuristic telescope so the disk/portal is easier observed.

Comment: @Jules There's something sweet and encouraging about seeing two amateurs discovering something like this so long as it is plausible, though. Perhaps make it more believable in that they didn't discover it at the same time, maybe an old club member teaching a young one the ropes and share his old photos and they discover it when scrutinizing the photos together.